# How to delete only first ocurrence of line without "}" in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I try to delete carriage return in a file, all lines have a "}" at end, but some lines, have a return carriage and the "}" its down.... Here an example of my code and file, but doesn't work. Thank You Very Much!!

[Original File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9LS2.png)

The line with "INGENIERIA Y SERVICIOS LOS NOGALES SPA" it's the conflict.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2KrF.png)

Code:

```
$InputFile='Original.txt'
$OutPutFile='NewFile.txt'
(Get-Content $InputFile) | ForEach-Object -Begin {
$results = @()
} -Process {
$out = $.Split("}").GetUpperBound(0)
[int]$iOut = [int]$out
if($iOut -lt 1){$.Replace("`r`n","")}else{$_}
} | Set-Content $OutPutFile
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can try `(Get-Content $InputFile -Raw) -replace '(?<!})\r\n' | Set-Content $outputfile`

Comment: do you need all those versions of PoSh? if not ... please remove the unneeded ones.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7571258)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
(Get-Content $InputFile -Raw) -replace '(?<!})\r\n' |
    Set-Content $outputfile
```

Reading a file using `Get-Content` without the `-Raw` or `-ReadCount` parameters, reads each line and outputs it as an array element. A line is output once its delimiter has been found. The default delimiter for `Get-Content` is the end of line character. `-Raw` allows newline characters to be preserved and the file is read as a single string.

`(?<!})` is a negative lookbehind matching only when the preceding character is not a `}`. Then we simply match `\r\n` for `CRLF`.